# Hide Parent Directories During FTP Login on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, ftp

I'm using Ubuntu Server 9.10 with ProFTP and Webmin.

I have things set up such that when the FTP user logs in, the user goes to /var/www/[domain]. The trouble is that I don't want them to see the /var/www part, just the [domain] part. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setting [`DefaultRoot`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html) to chroot a group to the `/var/www/[domain]` directory.

For example, this will chroot the group `group1` to `example.net`:

`DefaultRoot /var/www/example.net group1`

Add to proftpd.conf and restart ftpd.  The parameter after the path accepts boolean input.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. When using FireFTP, I still see the /var/www in the path. Perhaps this is a bash thing where I can chroot from a file in there?

Comment: Do you run the version of ProFTPD that supports it?

Comment: Well blow me down. It works now! I must have needed to restart again, or use /bin/rbash -- I did one of those two changes and all is well.

Comment: On the /bin/rbash, I edited the user accounts used for FTP and made certain their shell was /bin/rbash instead of /bin/sh or /bin/bash. Don't know if that was necessary, but that's what I did and then restarted ProFTPD.

Comment: You might consider using /bin/false or nologin instead unless the user actually needs shell access.